# Kotlin Http client. Add parameters from map to request

Tags: http, kotlin, get, kohttp

I use [kohttp](https://github.com/rybalkinsd/kohttp) to send requests to my service, but I got stuck.

Lets imagine that we have a function, that creates a request with some parameters that are represented as Map, and also append to them one or more additional param.

```
override fun request(urlString: String, params: Map<String, Any>?): Response {

    val response = httpGet {
        url = urlString
        param {
            "someName" to someValue
            // also add 'params' map to request parameters
        }
    }
    return  response;
}
```

How can we do so?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this should work:

```
param {
    "someName" to someValue
     params?.forEach { key, value ->
        key to value
    }
}
```